# Windbg Cannot load clr.dll when debugging Outlook plugin

Tags: c++, dll, windbg

I'm using windbg to do the dumpheap for a Outlook plugin. The plugin is written in C++

The environment is 32-bit. Outlook version is 2010. I'm not sure what the .net version is but seems there is onlt v4.0 that contains clr.dll

To start, I set the symbol path, and then attached to Outlook.

I used command ".load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll"

and use .chain to see, the result shows that the clr.dll is inside the chain.

```
0:013> .chain
Extension DLL search Path:
    C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\WINXP;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\winext;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\winext\arcade;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\pri;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\winext\arcade;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\;C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\bin32;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\
Extension DLL chain:
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll: image 4.0.30319.1022, built Tue Jan 07 22:55:34 2014
        [path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll]
    dbghelp: image 6.2.9200.16384, API 6.2.6, built Wed Jul 25 19:11:41 2012
        [path: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 6.2.9200.16384, API 1.0.0, built Wed Jul 25 19:16:43 2012
        [path: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 6.2.9200.16384, API 1.0.0, built Wed Jul 25 19:21:27 2012
        [path: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 6.2.9200.16384, API 1.0.0, built Wed Jul 25 19:21:18 2012
        [path: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 6.2.9200.16384, API 1.0.0, built Wed Jul 25 19:22:12 2012
        [path: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x86\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
```

However, when I use .cordll it shows there is no CLR DLL.

```
0:013> .cordll
CLR DLL status: No load attempts
```

I searched on web and tried some solution suggested by MSDN, like "use g to let program run for a while"

but the clr.dll is still not loaded no matter how long I wait.

Anyone can tell me where can I do a further try?

Or, is there another way that I can do the "!dumpheap -stat".

Thanks.

Comment: Start with `.loadby sos clr` and if SOS loads successfully you can then `!dumpheap -stat`.

Comment: Thanks LexLi, because the clr is not properly loaded, so if I used .loadby sos clr, windbg will tell me "Unable to find module clr", also if I give the direct path of sos.dll by using .load C:\XXXXXXXXXXXX\sos.dll then still nothing will happen, just like when I load clr

Comment: You get some misunderstanding. `clr.dll`, `sos`, and `!dumpheap -stat` are all for .NET managed module debugging. If your module is purely native, you cannot use any of such debugging approaches. Native debugging in WinDbg is different. If you do want to learn, start from good books, such as http://www.patterndiagnostics.com/index.php?q=publications

Comment: Thanks LexLi, I think these books will help: ）

Comment: As this looks like a native app then `!heap -stat` and `¬address -summary` maybe what you are looking for

Comment: Why do you want to debug .NET if your plugin is C++?